# Bean with RefreshScope in Pojo in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I am new to Spring boot, what I am having in my project is a Configuration Class annotated with RefreshScope and the same is used in a Pojo Class and a copy is stored in local variable inside constructer.

Please suggest how to refresh that local variable in Pojo Class

Code is as below

1. Configuration Class

```
    @Configuration
    @Getter
    @RefreshScope
    public class ProjectSetting {
    
        @Value("${security.enabled:true}")
        private boolean securityEnabled;
    
      
    }
```

2. Pojo Class

```
public class AssetTaggingEventProcessor
{
   private ProjectSetting projectSetting;
   AssetTaggingEventProcessor()
   {
         projectSetting = applicationContext.getBean(ProjectSetting.class);
   }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to refresh it, the class is a proxy delegating to the proper instance. So after refresh the proxy will reference to a new instance.

Comment: Thanks, it worked as mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @M.Deinum, It worked as you mentioned in comments, moreover I found detail explanation also on other posts that There will be a new proxy object will be prepared and then it will be replaced with actual object to Pojo will have reference to new object.